# Como adicionar um TextBox dinamicamente usando VB

Tags: vba, lista, textbox, microsoft-excel

Como adicionar um TextBox dinamicamente, sempre que o `Userform` (Caixa de Combinação ou Validação de Dados Lista) seja igual a `"Outro (Especificar)"`, usando `VB` ?

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou perdida, sou novata em fazer macros e formulários, usando `VB`. ^^'

Estava fazendo com Validação de Dados, Lista.

```
Sub Outro()
'
' Outro Macro
coluna = 1
linha = 1
While Cells(linha, coluna).Value <> ""
    Application.Visible = False 'torna invisível a aplicação Excel
    valorCelula = Format(Cells(linha, coluna).Value, 2)
    'If valorCelula <> Cells(linha, coluna).Value Then
    '    Cells(linha, coluna).Value = valorCelula
    'End If
    linha = linha + 1
    With Selection.Font
            .Color = -16776961
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Range("G3").Select
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1", Link:=False, _
           DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=497.25, Top:=36, Width:=66.75, Height:= _
           10.5).Select
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Seja muito bem vinda à comunidade SOpt Dani Guido, considere dar uma olhada em [Como Perguntar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), irá ajudar bastante. Então, em relação ao seu problema, não consegui compreender o que exatamente você quer, tente **acrescentar alguns detalhes, partes do código que você utilizou e não está entendendo, qual linguagem de programação você quer usar?**

Comment: Estou com uma planilha de excel, que tenho de adicionar um campo lista, na mesma terá uma opção de "Outro", quando escolhida irar abrir um campo para ser preenchido. Programação em VB, usando macro e tal.  Ex: (Titulo)> Ponto:      (Opções) >   A; B; C; Outros(Especificar).

Comment: Tente seguir [esses passos!](http://www.macoratti.net/14/04/vba_forma1.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Clica com o botão direito sobre o ComboBox e vai em:

[image: Comando atribuir macro...]

Clica em Novo na tela que aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu usei este código no sub `Dropdown1_Alteração`

```
Set oTB = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1")
Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("C2")
With oTB
.Name = "MyTB"
.LinkedCell = "$C$2"
.Left = cell.Left
.Top = cell.Top
.Width = cell.Width
.Height = cell.Height
.Object.BackColor = RGB(204, 204, 255)
.Object.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
.Object.Text = "Texto"
End With
```